# ¿Como obtener el ID del usuario que acabo de dar de alta en una tabla mysql desde java?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, insert

mi duda es simple, quiero obtener el ID del usuario que di de alta en una tabla al hacer un insert.
Tomando en cuenta que el id es auto_increment.
necesito que después de dar de alta ese usuario su id se almacene en una variable para luego hacer una consulta con ese id.
este es mi función para dar de alta usuarios,
de ante mando, muchas gracias:

```
 public void alta() throws SQLException{
try{
 Connection con = Db.connect3();
 String SQL = null;
 String nivel = "1";
 String token = "1";
 //Obtener fecha 
 java.util.Date fecha = new Date();
 //Fecha y hora
 DateFormat fechaHora = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 //Parsear fecha a String
 String fe = fechaHora.format(fecha);
 nc.net(txt_pass.getText());
 Object ob = nc.parsearJson();
 SQL = "INSERT INTO    users(name,email,password,remember_token,nivel_usuario,created_at) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

 PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(SQL);

st.setString(1, txt_name.getText());
st.setString(2, txt_usuarios.getText());
st.setString(3, (String) ob);
st.setString(4, token);
st.setString(5, nivel);
st.setString(6, fe);
st.execute();
Db db = new Db();//llamar la clase db
db.cerrarConexion();//llamar la función cerrar conexión
if(txt_name.getText().length()>0 && 
(txt_pass.getText().length()>0))
             {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Añadido correctamente");    

}

}catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error " + e );
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es es muy fácil si estas usando `PreparedStatement` puedes usar `ResultSet` para obtener los resultados como el id que estas generando automáticamente.

```
//modificar tu execute
st.executeUpdate();
ResultSet result = st.getGeneratedKeys();
if (result.next()) {
    int idDevuelto = rs.getInt(1);
    System.out.println(idDevuelto);
}
```

Comment: Muchas muchas gracias amigo!